# Where can I see which StackExchange websites are in their preparatory phase (in beta) and thus will be launched in the main stream soon?

Tags: support

I am sorry to ask this question here — I just didn't know where I could ask it. It's not about english.se, it's generally about all the sites on stack exchange.

Feel free to close it or even delete it (but giving an answer prior to that would really be appreciated).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for http://area51.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: Thank you, Hellion!!! Now I am on my way to get this question deleted.